# Movie not loaded for SWF

Tags: c#, flash, shockwave

So I'm using visual studio 2019.

I got some code trying to embed a SWF from Doodletoo.com

It loads to 100% and then goes to a black screen. When I right click it says movie not loaded. I've added the Flash variables & the link for the SWF. The button simply starts the SWF. I don't understand though. I managed to get it to load only once. When it did load it caused extreme lag.

Here is my script for the form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NewtTEst
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            axShockwaveFlash1.Stop();
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://doodletoo.com/flash/DoodleToo2.swf?v=21";
            axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars = "configUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fdoodletoo%2Ecom%2F%2Fconfig%2Exml&amp;roomID=4&amp;useRefresh=false&amp;isEmbed=false&amp;v=21";
            axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't load the SWF? When I replace the current SWF link with another SWF link. It works fine, playing the SWF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct link is:

http://doodletoo.com/flash/DoodleToo2.swf?v=21&configUrl=http://doodletoo.com//config.xml&roomID=4&useRefresh=false&isEmbed=false&v=21

Untested but you can try solving with...

**(1)** Put flashvars in the same URL of SWF.

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://doodletoo.com/flash/DoodleToo2.swf?v=21&configUrl=http://doodletoo.com//config.xml&roomID=4&useRefresh=false&isEmbed=false&v=21";
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
}
```

**(2)** Change format of your flashvars. Test either Format A or Format B.

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://doodletoo.com/flash/DoodleToo2.swf?v=21";
    axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars = "configUrl=http://doodletoo.com//config.xml&roomID=4&useRefresh=false&isEmbed=false&v=21";
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
}
```

Format A:

```
configUrl=http://doodletoo.com//config.xml&roomID=4&useRefresh=false&isEmbed=false&v=21
```

Format B:

```
configUrl=http://doodletoo.com//config.xml;roomID=4;useRefresh=false;isEmbed=false;v=21
```

Comment: Any way I could add WMode=Opaque to that URL?

Comment: I got a variable I need to change as well. The path to the variable displays this ``root|DT2.swf|scripts|com|wdf|doodletoo|ToolController`` How could I add that path to this ``Game.SetVariable("_root.RESTOFTHEPATHHERE, "999999");``

Comment: I've asked a new question, seeking help about the above comment. I'm not sure if you could help me or not, but you seem like you know what you're doing so I'd figured I'd ask you.